# Timer from setInterval playing 4 times faster when played in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I'm building a JavaScript-based music instrument with a loop option.
To create the loop, first record the notes, their duration, gap (between notes) and total time for the whole loop.

For example, that's how I record the gap between notes:

```
$('.pad').on('touchstart', function(){
    if (gapCount != null) {
        clearInterval(gapCount)
        loopInfo.push(noteInfo);
    }
    gapCount = setInterval(function () {
        noteInfo.gap++
    },1);
})
```

After I am recording the time for the gap and the total duration (in milliseconds), I am passing the information to the playing loop function. Then instead of pausing between notes  the amount of time I have just recorded, it is playing everything 4 times faster. This is really odd, what is the reason for that behavior?

```
gap = loopInfo[i].gap;
setTimeout(function () {
    PlayNoteInLoop(i)
}, gap) // the same number recorded in the function above, but in reality playing it 4 times faster`
```

Comment: Read http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ to understand how timers work. If you need precise timing, look at the  window.requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Still weird, this is not minor inaccuracy. It's damn 4 times faster!